# Are io_submit writes() guaranteed to be executed in order?

Tags: c, linux

Does io_submit() system call in Linux guarantees the order of the execution of each operation submitted by multiple sequential io_submit()s by the same process ?

Consider the following example:
I submit some write() operations on a file descriptor , like:

```
io_prep_pwrite(iocb_ptrs[0],fd,&buf1,buf1_len,buf1_offset);
io_prep_pwrite(iocb_ptrs[1],fd,&buf2,buf2_len,buf2_offset);
io_submit(ctx,2,&iocb_ptrs[0]);
```

Just immediately after submitting the first io_submit the process submits data again:

```
io_prep_pwrite(iocb_ptrs[2],fd,&buf3,buf3_len,buf3_offset);
io_prep_pwrite(iocb_ptrs[3],fd,&buf4,buf4_len,buf4_offset);
io_submit(ctx,2,&iocb_ptrs[2]);
```

If the buf3_offset happens to be the same value as buf1_offset, does the possibility of overwrite of the data in buf3 by the data in buf1 exists ?
Consider that we have a multicore system and the process that does aio submission is running on the core1. (note: we have only one user process) First io_submit() happened and the core1 started to write the data to disk. But then an network interrupt occurs and the core1 has to stop the first io_submit() to attend the interrupt. Now, the core2 is idle , it takes the second io_submit() call and sends the data to disk. When core1 returns from the interrupt it will continue to work on the the first io_submit() and the data that I asked the process to write first, will actually be written last.

Can this happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what happened to [this manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/io.3.html) with an overview of linux async io, but it clearly states that "the operations are carried out in arbitrary order and more than one operation for one file descriptor can be started." So it seems like your nervousness is justified.

Comment: libaio has an entry point for this call rather than using syscall to implement it. And as rici points point the operations are not guaranteed to be carried out in any order.

Comment: @rici I think you're thinking of [glibc's **POSIX** AIO manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Asynchronous-I_002fO.html) (POSIX AIO is different to Linux AIO). Nonetheless, your warning that **you can't depend on asynchronous completion order** is still very correct. In the kernel I/Os can be reordered/merged/split. Below the kernel, whether asynchronously submitted I/O is completed in the submitted order is device dependent (e.g. SCSI lets a device choose for via whether it supports SIMPLE TASK or ORDERED TASKS where SIMPLE means commands can complete in any order).

Comment: @anon: the question and my answer are about interfaces provided in libaio.h, which is not a Posix interface. I fixed the decayed link in the four-year-old answer by changing Ubuntu version names (which avoids Ubuntu's manpage server from translating the request to an only vaguely related interface for a different programming environment.

Comment: @rici Hmm I see what you mean and I stand corrected. The original manpage is still carried in "downstream" mirrors of the libaio project (such as https://pagure.io/libaio/blob/master/f/man/io.3 ) but I guess the "io" manpage has become shadowed by an io manpage from another project in Ubuntu. Given the pages have very similar text I wonder whether one was written with copied text from the other?